# How to use LINQ to group objects in two groups

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, group-by

Lets say that I have the class Invoice:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int PartNumber { get; set; }

    public string PartDescription { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

and then I have an array of its objects in the variable **arrayOfInvoices** .

If I had to Group invoices in two groups- invoices with Unit price below 12 and invoices with unit price above or equal to 12 and display details about invoices in each group sorted in ascending order of the price, how could I do that ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do something like this:

```
var results = 
    from inv in arrayOfInvoices 
    orderby inv.Price
    group inv by inv.Price < 12;
```

Or if you prefer fluent syntax:

```
var results = arrayOfInvoices.OrderBy(inv => inv.Price)
                             .GroupBy(inv => inv.Price < 12);
```

To group the invoices into three or more 'buckets', you can use [`BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var priceBoundaries = new[] { 12m, 20m };
var results = 
    from inv in arrayOfInvoices  
    orderby inv.Price
    let index = Array.BinarySearch(priceBoundaries, inv.Price)
    group inv by (index < 0 ? ~index : index + 1);
```

Or use side effects, like this:

```
var priceBoundaries = new[] { 12m, 20m, Decimal.MaxValue }; // Note the addition of MaxValue
var i = 0;
var results = 
    from inv in arrayOfInvoices 
    orderby inv.Price
    group inv by (inv.Price < priceBoundaries[i] ? i : ++i);
```

<sup>This is generally bad practice, but should perform better than the BinarySearch method above.</sup>

Comment: @KevinDeLorey Yes, I just included the fluent syntax as well.

Comment: I guess that it will work but what happens if I wanted to group them in three groups <= 12 , >12 and <=20 , >20 ?

Answer (score 2):

If using group function is a pain (sometimes it gets annoying), then you can also use "Where"

```
var invoices = new List<Invoice> ();
var group1= invoices.Where(i=> i.Price<12).Orderby(i=> i.Price).ToList();
var group2= invoices.Where(i=> i.Price>=12).Orderby(i=> i.Price).ToList();
```

Comment: Nothing inherently wrong with this answer, so I'll balance the down-vote.

Comment: ... other than it looping through the whole input twice and performing twice as many comparisons as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate the concept of the range in a class:

```
private class PriceRange<T> : IEquatable<PriceRange<T>>
{
    public T Min { get; set; }
    public T Max { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 31 + Min.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 31 + Max.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as PriceRange<T>);
    }

    public bool Equals(PriceRange<T> other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;

        if (!Min.Equals(other.Min)) return false;
        if (!Max.Equals(other.Max)) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then use a map function to map the prices of each of your invoices to the appropriate range:

```
private class PriceRangeFactory<T>
{
    public PriceRangeFactory(T[] rangeCutoffs)
    {
        _RangeCutoffs = rangeCutoffs;
    }

    private T[] _RangeCutoffs;

    public PriceRange<T> Map(T price)
    {
        var index = Array.BinarySearch(_RangeCutoffs, price);
        // Assume that the _RangeCutoffs that we have fully cover all possible values for T.
        if (index < 0) index = ~index;

        return new PriceRange<T>() { Min = _RangeCutoffs[index - 1], Max = _RangeCutoffs[index] };
    }
}
```

Then use GroupBy with that map function:

```
var rangeFactory = new PriceRangeFactory<decimal>(new decimal[] { decimal.MinValue, 12, 20, decimal.MaxValue });
var grouped = foos.GroupBy(a => rangeFactory.Map(a.Price));
```

You get a list of IGroupings each keyed by a range that you specified, with the appropriate objects that fit into that range attached.

Now, obviously the code above is not quite production level, but it should be enough to get you started. As for why its not production level:

- There's no check to assert that the ranges supplied to the PriceRangeFactory actually do fully cover all possible values.
- It always assumes that the range is described as > X and <= Y.
- There's no checking around Range.Min < Range.Max.
- There's no assert that the list of range cutoffs supplied to the PriceRangeFactory are ordered correctly (required for BinarySearch).
- There are bound to be some edge cases I haven't covered.